# Why even Lord Vishnu put Tilak (Gopi-Chandan) on his forehead?

Tags: vishnu, scripture, vaishnavism, tilak

As a pure Vaishnav Devotee, we are putting a tilak on our head, But why lord himself putting Tilak on his forehead.? Is there any logic behind? any scriptures mentioned this logic?please share your idea.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure really Vishnu, Shiva put their tilaks. See my question [What Tilak or Namam does Lord Brahma have on His forehead?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11750/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer: Yeah, But here I am specifically mention lord vishnu, Because he is the source of everything as we know, and what he do, it has some meaning ,so there is some-thing big reason why lord Vishnu  put tilak on his forhead

Comment: No debate please but there are people who think Vishnu as not Supreme, for Shaivaites Shiva is source of everything and for Shaktas Devi is source of everything. Myself being an Advaitin, believes Brahman is consciousness and Consciousness (Brahman) alone is pure and when we realize it Maya vanishes and so Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra. I believe that Brahman has no linga bheda and he can be called by any name as i'm Advaitin.

Comment: @TheDestroyer: yeah brother so, that's why I mention Lord Vishnu in my question , I know you are follower of Lord Shiva, I don't want to hurt your belief towards lord shiva,that's not my intension and here is my question not like who is supreme?.So,Believe what your heart says, Worship with true devotion,That's it .

Comment: @TheDestroyer: Jay Shree Krishna, Om namo Narayan :)

Comment: No issues. My comment is for your statement, **he is the source of everything as we know**.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, No debate, It's my belief, you did your comment, so that's it , no more debate for Lord Vishnu and Shiva.Eventually we can choose what ever form we like to worship ..Jay Shree krishna :)

Answer (score 2):

Krishna and Vishnu are taken as identical in many respects. What I found for Krishna has been mentioned in the wtitings of Vilva-mangala:

> kasturi-tilakam lalAtafalake bakshas-sthale kausuvam. Meaning : **Sri Krishna wears a tilaka of Kasturi** on His forehead and Kaustubha-gem on His chest.

**I did not find mention of gopi-chandana** in this regard anywhere.

Sri Rama was a King and He is expected to wear the Raja-tilaka.But the dhyana-slokas I checked does not mention any.

Reference: Stavakusumanjali, Swami Gambhirananda (Ed.), Udbodhan