# What does the Vaishnavite Tilaka mean when worn by Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, tilak

Vishnu is always depicted as wearing the caste-mark of Vaishnavites.  But I believe it represents Vishnu's foot-mark when worn by Vishnu's devotees, who show their devotion through it.

It has to mean something different when Vishnu wears it - since it is hard to imagine Vishnu putting His foot on His own forehead.

The Shaivite mark of ashes applies to Shiva Himself since all it represents is the ephemeral nature of existence.

Comment: Already asked here [Why even Lord Vishnu put Tilak (Gopi-Chandan) on his forehead?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12476/3500)

Comment: the other question is about any tilak,  my question is why he wears the same mark worn by his devotees. @TheDestroyer