# In most of the TV serials, it's shown that Lord Vishnu or Krishna apply Urdhva Pundrak and Lord Shiva applies tripundra. Is there a scriptural basis?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, temple, tilak

Kindly provide with any scriptural basis for the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a forum for the accuracy of tv writers

Comment: What is wrong with asking if is there any scriptural basis that suggest Gods wear tilaka?

Comment: Doest answer the question, but just a hint that they also apply the tilak- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44949/21353

Answer (score 3):

- #### Yes, Śiva applies the Tripuṇḍra (त्रिपुंड्र).

The Śiva Purāṇa's Verse [1.24.11](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit/d/doc385346.html) say so:

> [Chapter 24](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225962.html) - The greatness of the holy ashes (bhasma), Section 1 - Vidyeśvara-saṃhitā, Śiva Purāṇa
>
> शिवेन विष्णुना चैव तथा तिर्यक्त्रिपुंड्रकम् ।
> उमादेवी च लक्ष्मींश्च वाचान्याभिश्च नित्यशः ॥ ११ ॥
>  ब्राह्मणैः क्षत्रियैर्वैश्यैः शूद्रै रपि च संस्करैः ।
> अपभ्रंशैर्धृतं भस्मत्रिपुंड्रोद्धूलनात्मना ॥ १२ ॥
>
> > 11. & 12. **Śiva, Viṣṇu, Umā, Lakṣmī, goddess of speech and other gods and goddesses, brahmins, kṣatriyas, vaiśyas and persons of mixed castes and hill tribes have observed Tripuṇḍra and dusting (Uddhūlana) always.**
>
> English Translation by J.L Shastri

---

- #### Visnu wears the Ūrdhvapuṇḍra (ऊर्ध्वपुण्ड्र) tilaka.

Padma Purāṇa Verse [6.229.137](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/padma-purana-sanskrit/d/doc479844.html) says so:

> [Chapter 229](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana) - Uttara-Khaṇḍa, Padma-purāṇa
>
> तन्मध्ये कर्णिकायां तु समासीनो जनार्दनः । शुद्धजांबूनदप्रख्यो
> मुक्ताहारविभूषितः ॥ १३३ ॥
>
> > 133. In it, in the pericarp, is seated Viṣṇu. He is like pure gold, and is
> >      adorned with a necklace of pearl
>
> .....
>
> षोडशाब्दवयो रूपयौवनेन विराजितः । विशालभालदेशे तु कुंकुमेन सुगंधिना ॥
> १३६ ॥ **रचितेनोर्ध्वपुंड्रेण सीमंतेनोपशोभितः** । मथितामृतफेनाभ
> शुक्लवस्त्रसुवेष्टितः ॥ १३७ ॥
>
> > 136. & 137.  He is graced with rows of white He is adorned with youth
> >      proper for the age and form of (a lad of) sixteen years. **He is graced
> >      with an upright, fragrant mark (Ūrdhvapuṇḍra) made with saffron**, and
> >      the parting line of hair. He is well covered with a white garment
> >      resembling the foam of nectar that was churned (out of the ocean).
>
> English Translation by N.A. Deshpande